# Modifying jQuery progressbar's color based on Gridview column

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, progress-bar

I'm trying to modify the color of progressbar based on a boloean value in each row in gridview (a Boolean Value)  If the value is True the color will be Green and if the value is False the color will be Red. but for some reason the condition for setting color is not working!

Thanks In Advance:

Asp GridView Code:

```
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="progress" HeaderText="Progress" SortExpression="progress" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="status" SortExpression="status" />
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
   <div class="pbcontainer">
      <div class="progressbar"><span><%# Eval("progress") %>%</span></div>
      <div class="value" style="visibility:hidden; height:0; width:0;"> <%#         Eval("progress") %> </div>
      <div class="status" style="visibility:hidden; height:0; width:0;"> <%# Eval("status") %> </div>
  </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Script:

```
</style>

<link href="CSS/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3%20.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.pbcontainer').each(function () {
            var val = parseInt($(".value", this).text());
            var status = $(".status", this).text();

            var progressColor = "Orange";
            var progressBackColor = "lightYellow";

            console.log(status);
            if (status == "False") {
                progressColor = "Red";
                //console.log("Condition met color red status Flase");
            }
            else if (status == "True") {
                progressColor = "Green";
                //console.log(progressColor);
                //console.log("Condition not met color Green status True");
            }

            $('.progressbar', this).progressbar({ value: val });
            $('.progressbar', this).css({ 'background': progressBackColor });
            $('.progressbar > div', this).css({ 'background': progressColor });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What does console.log(status) say?

Comment: @mahdilamb i checked on 2 rows of data! and the `console.log(status);` displays the right date ! for example first row as `False`

Comment: @mahdilamb but some how the ones in if statement not working 
however when i changed the `else if` to `else` that one displayed and changed all the progressbars to green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the extra white-space around the status the condition is not true..

You need to modify your code to trim the white space like this

```
 var status = $.trim( $(".status", this).text() );
```

Check this demo
http://jsfiddle.net/aXTcV/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.pbcontainer').each(function () {
            var this_Progress = $(this);
            var val = parseInt($.trim(this_Progress.find('.value').text()));
            var status = $.trim(this_Progress.find('.status').text())

            var progressColor = "Orange";
            var progressBackColor = "lightYellow";

            console.log(status);
            if (status == "False") {
                progressColor = "Red";
                //console.log("Condition met color red status Flase");
            }
            else if (status == "True") {
                progressColor = "Green";
                //console.log(progressColor);
                //console.log("Condition not met color Green status True");
            }
            this_Progress.find('.progressbar').progressbar({ value: val });
            this_Progress.find('.ui-progressbar').css({ 'background': progressBackColor });
            this_Progress.find('.ui-progressbar-value').css({ 'background': progressColor });

        });
    });
</script>
```